# Resizing Chrome breaks layout

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, responsive-design

I have the below HTML and CSS. As far as I can see it is valid and should work, indeed it works in IE and FF no problem. Chrome however, has recently broken. When I resize in Chrome it firstly collapses as per the media query rules, but when expanding again the right hand content is shifted down a line.

If I inspect the `.side` element, reapply (un-tick then tick) the `position: absolute` then it redraws and fixes the problem.

Is my code at fault here or do I need to raise a bug with Chrome?

Also, this only broke very recently (I've been developing for a while) but because of Chrome's auto-update I'm not sure if I've recently been updated.

http://codepen.io/mrchris/pen/AJwrI

HTML:

```
<nav id="site-subnav">

    <a href="#">Features</a>
    <a href="#">Technical</a>
    <a href="#">Pricing</a>

    <div class="side">
        <a href="#" class="button clear positive">Try It Free</a>
        <a href="#" class="button clear">Buy</a>
    </div>

</nav>
```

CSS

```
#site-subnav
{
    background: #eee;
}

#site-subnav a {
  display: inline-block;
}

#site-subnav .side
{
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 500px)
{
    #site-subnav a
    {
        display: block;
    }

    #site-subnav .side
    {
        position: relative;
        right: 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `top:7px` to `.side`. This will keep it at the proper y-offset.

Answer (score 0):

See my codepen.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LdyJq

I changed the nav position to be relative.

Comment: I don't believe so, if I inspect them when the viewport is back to it's full size then they state `display: inline-block`. They should only be `block` under a certain size.

Comment: Ah, I see what you want. I'll take another look.

Answer (score 0):

You might be right, I wasn't able to figure out exactly what is wrong with your code. It works fine in FF, but Chrome seems to render the right side weird after resizing.

That said, this may be an acceptable workaround. In this example you would just wrap the A elements in another DIV, then float both inline-block DIVs on opposing sides. When width <500px, the DIV and A elements would become blocks. Use a clearfix to preserve the #site-subnav height.

CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Drbcq

HTML:

```
<nav id="site-subnav">
  <div class="lside">
    <a href="#">Features</a>
    <a href="#">Technical</a>
    <a href="#">Pricing</a>
  </div>
  <div class="rside">
    <a href="#" class="button clear positive">Try It Free</a>
    <a href="#" class="button clear">Buy</a>
  </div>
  <div class="cf"></div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
#site-subnav
{
    background: #eee;
}

#site-subnav .rside, #site-subnav .lside
{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

#site-subnav .rside
{
    float:right;
}

#site-subnav .lside
{
    float:left;
}

@media (max-width: 500px)
{
    #site-subnav a,
    #site-subnav .rside,
    #site-subnav .lside
    {
        display:block;
        float:none;
    }
}

/* clearfix */
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}
```